# How to play one sound at a time?

Tags: android, eclipse, audio, media, imagebutton

When i click a imgniatp at the display, audio play very well, but if i click imgbukap too, before audio of imgniatp finish, imgbukap also play audio. so both audio play together. How to play one sound at a time?

```
package sodik.com.ramadhan;

import sodik.com.ramadhan.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class Puasa3Activity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
MediaPlayer mp;
ImageButton imgniatp1, imgbukap2;

String p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.puasa3);

    TextView p1tk = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.p1tk);
    TextView p2tk = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.p2tk);

    imgniatp1=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgniatp);
    imgniatp1.setOnClickListener(this);
    imgbukap2=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgbukap);
    imgbukap2.setOnClickListener(this);
}
    public void onClick(View v){
        switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.imgniatp:
            mp= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bukapuasa);
            mp.setVolume(1,1);
            mp.start();
            Toast.makeText(this, " Memainkan Buka Puasa", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
        case R.id.imgbukap:
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.niatpuasa);
            mp.setVolume(1,1);
            mp.start();
            Toast.makeText(this, " Mainkan Niat Puasa ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
        }


            }
```

`

Comment: If I understand, what you are trying to ask is **how to play one sound at a time**?

Answer (score 0):

You could check to see if the `MediaPlayer` is already playing something, and start the clip in an `onCompletionListener` if it is

```
if(mp != null && mp.isPlaying()) {
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.bukapuasa);
            mp.start();
        }
    });
} else {
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.bukapuasa);
    mp.start();
}
```